# Vs2019+vs2022 avoid breaking on Xamarin.Essentials.FeatureNotSupportedException

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2019, xamarin.essentials, visual-studio-2022

When using sensors such as barometer,compas etc. in Xamarin.Forms you cannot check if the sensor is available but have to try starting it and then catch the exception, if it is not there, such as here.

```
try
{
  Barometer.Start(SensorSpeed.Game);
}      
catch
{
  //failed
}
```

The issue is that this happens every single time, I debug on a device without these sensors, and though I catch the exception, I break into it all the time.

The exception is

```
Xamarin.Essentials.FeatureNotSupportedException: 'Specified method is not supported.'
```

but when I, in exception settings, uncheck that one from "break when thrown", it *still* breaks on the exception.
This derives from

```
System.NotSupportedException
```

which i then *also* uncheck, and still it breaks on it.
The next levels up are
System.SystemException
System.Exception
which I can uncheck to stop breaking when thrown, but I would rather do that, since then everything is effectively not breaking if caught, which I would still like.

Comment: maybe your android version is blocking it.